# Issue Consuming REST API Magento

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I have been struggling with connecting to my Magento store through the REST API.
I ve tried connecting as a stand alone program running from XAMPP: here is the code:

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "http://healthandmed.com/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl =
"http://healthandmed.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" .
urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://healthandmed.com/admin123/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://healthandmed.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://healthandmed.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) &&
$_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
   $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
   $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION
: OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
   $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,
OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
   $oauthClient->enableDebug();
   if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
       $requestToken =
$oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
       $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
       $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
       header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . 
$requestToken['oauth_token']);
       exit;
   } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
       $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
       $accessToken =
$oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
       $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
       $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
       $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
       header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
       exit;
   } else {
       $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
       $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
       $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
       $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
       echo count($productsList);
   }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
   print_r($e);
}
    ?>
```

I have also tried the tutorial at Inchoo:
/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/

Both solutions lead me to the same place:
http://healthandmed.com/admin123/oauth_authorize
with the following error message:
"An error occurred. Your authorization request is invalid."

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: generally better to put the code here instead of pastebin

Comment: fixed. Thank. I' ve been a long time lurker here. This is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your Admin Authorization Url i.e. **$adminAuthorizationUrl** the URL has to be http://healthandmed.com/admin/oauth_authorize, replace 'admin123' with 'admin'. When you do this you will be prompted to login to magento admin backend then you will be asked to Authorize.